# HighCharts - Need more space between bottom of chart and Xaxis labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get more space between my highcharts plotArea and the xAxis... nothing so far seems to be working.  The picture shows how close they are and I am wanting to add about 30 more px to it.

Thank you for the help!!

[image]

Comment: Can you explain it better ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I unerstand your question correctly...

Here is a standard `xAxis` and an altered `yAxis` from the [Highcharts documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels).

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-x/

---

Now, here is a fork of that fiddle, but with the **labels** of the `xAxis` pushed further down.

http://jsfiddle.net/BCPL5/

The relevant Highcharts API documentation:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels

---

The alteration to the `xAxis` is in this statement.

```
    ...

    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            y: 25
        }
    },

    ...
```

---

Now, you could also use [offset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.offset), as can be seen in the Highcharts example below, but I don't believe that is what you want in this case.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/offset/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set min/maxPadding http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.minPadding